# How to call a variable from .droid to .shared project in VS Xamarin?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin.forms

this may be a very basic question but I'd like to ask if how can I output the variable from a .droid to a .shared project in VS Xamarin. Let's say I have a variable with value in a renderer from a .droid, then I'd like to call it from a .shared page. How can I do this?

ScannerPageRenderer.cs (From .droid)

```
try
{
  var BarcodeText = result.text.ToString();
  var BarcodeType = result.typeText.ToString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a ScannerPageRenderer then this means that you are using a custom Renderer for a Xamarin.Forms page.

To pass back the values you can either create public properties in the Page, for this example let's call it `ScannerPage` then pass the values in the `Element` object of the custom renderer as this is the Page you are attaching the custom renderer.

ex

```
private void Scan()
{
    //or however you are getting the result...
    var result = getScanResult();

    var scanPage = Element as ScannerPage;    

    if (scanPage == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    scanPage.BarcodeText = result.text.ToString();
    scanPage.BarcodeType = result.typeText.ToString();
}
```

Another way would be that instead of the two properties you create a public method where you pass in the `result` object the same way as above with the properties. In such method you will then assign your properties or fields with the values.

```
private void Scan()
{
    var result = getScanResult();

    var scanPage = Element as ScannerPage;    

    if (scanPage == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    scanPage.OnScanCompleted(result);
}
```

Hope this helps.-

Comment: Therefore, should I put this code in my ScannerPage.xaml.cs in .shared project? In which part there did the code processed by getting the variable value from ScannerPageRenderer.cs?

Comment: Or to make the question pretty simple, how can I call the variable from ScannerPageRenderer.cs in .droid project to a ScannerPage.cs in .shared project?

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. The code above is to be called from the Renderer class. The Page cannot access this variables but the custom renderer can access the Page so as explained above you just need to set the values from the Renderer to the Page using either properties or a method.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I really appreciate it. :-)